# Capture The Original URL After A Redirect?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, devise

I am using Rails 3 and Devise for authentication.

I want to track whenever a user enters my site from another domain or by typing in the URL. Assume the following page on my site:

`http://www.mysite.com/somepage`

If a visitor requests this URL by clicking a link on another site or types it in to his browser, I want to put the URL into a cookie for later use.  If `/somepage` does not require login it works fine. In a `before_filter` I just check to see if the referrer is not from `mysite.com`.

However, when `/somepage` requires a login, Devise makes a redirect, which results in a second request to my login page. The original referrer is carried forward to the new request.  So my code thinks it's the original requested URL and overwrites the cookie.  Wrong.

I'm probably just having a mental block, but I can't see how to determine that the page that is redirected to is not original page requested.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably get some ideas from this [article](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Redirect-back-to-current-page-after-sign-in,-sign-out,-sign-up,-update).

It seems like you should filter out anything that includes the user path, since you have no problem getting the referrer if the page doesn't require login.

So for example you could use a regex to filter out users/sign_in, users/sign_out, etc.

```
request.referrer = request.fullpath unless request.fullpath =~ /\/users/
```

or

```
request.env['HTTP_REFERER'] = request.fullpath unless request.fullpath =~ /\/users/
```

You would need to put this in some kind of `before_filter` above the `authenticate before_filter` so it is called first.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  That won't work because the user might enter the site via the login page ro signup page.